# accessing / plotting rows and columns from tables - R

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, multiple-columns

```
Ratings = read.table("Ratings.txt", 
           sep="\t", 
           col.names=c("User", "MId", "Rating"), 
           fill=FALSE, 
           strip.white=TRUE)

l = colnames(Ratings)[2]
```

This would give me the 2nd column - ("MId")

However I would like to get the third row in the column "MId"

I try:

```
k = colnames(Ratings)[2][3]
```

But this give me N/A. How do I access the rows and columns.
And if I can, do I just plot them like:

```
plot(MId~Rating)
```

Comment: For best results, try to ask just one question at a time. Using `colnames` doesn't give you the column, it gives you the *name* of the column. If you want the third value in the column, user standard row/col indexing `Ratings[3,2]`. For plotting, just do `plot(MId~Rating, Ratings)`. Both of these are very basic operations. You should consider reading some [introductory R material](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html).

Comment: Cheers, will read the whole shebang before posting another Q

Comment: You may be using `attach` in you think that `plot(MId~Rating)` will produce anything. You should abandon that practice and instead learn to use data arguments when available and `with` when not.

Comment: Removed [table] tag. `read.table` dows not create a table-object using hte specific terminology of hte R language.